# Freelancing while being Employed in Germany

Tags: taxes, germany

I am an expat living in Germany for 2 years now. My question is how to report one-time freelance earnings and how to register as a **part-time** and **one-time** freelancer, considering my situation:

- I am a full-time employee
- My visa permits self-employment
- In 2019 I took a side project on upWork (one-time, billed less than 2000 eur. in total)

I haven't registered as a "freelancer" beforehand since I thought there is a way to add **small additional income** in the normal tax return forms. It turns out that in any case one has to be registered as a freelancer.

I am a bit worried about my situation since I have to register "retroactively" (if it is even possible) and then get a 2nd Steuernummer and file my tax return.

I would like to be clean and report those earnings, but don't know how to do that..

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I also don't know if it makes sense to get a tax advisor/consultant.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Finanzamt" of the "Landkreis" where you are registered to live (your "Wohnsitz"). Take ALL your documentation with you. Explain this situation to them (again, backed up with the relevant docs). They will not try to trick you - completely trustworthy. But the answer could be complicated and bureaucratic, so get in writing what they say you should do.